# How to get email address while integrating google login in android

Tags: android, google-plus

I need to integrate the google plus login in my application.I have seen the samples and library which are given by google libraries. I have searched alot to get email but no use. Can anybody know please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two methods available to do this, both are documented [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/people#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address)

**Edit:**

There is also a web OAuth example for the web [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/#retrieve_an_authenticated_users_email_address)

However, Google+ Sign-In is not a requirement for getting the `userinfo.email` scope. You could do a simple OAuth flow and then use the returned tokens to also retrieve the address. Used Google+ for simplicity.

Comment: Hey Thank you so much It has worked for me. Can you please tell me how to get email while using OAuth. I have set the scope but don't know how to retrieve email id.

Comment: Edited my answer to also add the links for doing the same from the web or were you asking about an OAuth flow within Android?

Comment: Yeah.. I am speaking to get email address using OAuth flow within android